# Need help on choosing locks for thread synchronization

Tags: synchronization, locking, pthreads

I have several modifying threads and some reading threads, which all access the global variable X. I want to make my synchronization policy like this:

When a thread try to modify X, it will require a lock first, and several modifying threads can have several locks required.

When a thread try to read X, it must wait until all the modifying threads drop their locks.

Is there any solution to this situation in linux pthread library? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a read/write lock (or reader-writer lock).  I believe [there is one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/apis/users_86.htm) in pthreads (pthread_rwlock_*).